# what is behind the operator OR inside assignment operators?

Tags: python

i know the mechanics behind from operator OR, but in this case why the output is 7 ? what is behind?

```
x = int(5)
x = x | 3
print(x)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `|` is a bitwise OR operator; `5 | 3 = 0b101 | 0b11 = 0b111 = 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or` is different from `|`. The first one is a logical operator and is mainly used with boolean values, but the second one is called a bitwise operator. It works with the binary values of the operands.

5 = 101 in binary

3 = 011 in binary

The bitwise or i.e. `|` will perform an or operation of the corresponding bits (1 or 0 = 1, 0 or 1 = 1, 1 or 1 = 1) to get 111 i.e. 7

There's also bitwise and `&` and bitwise not `~`, in case you're curious